# CircleCI not picking up correct Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, circleci

I'm specifying Ruby version 2.2.2 in my `Gemfile` and `.ruby-version` file but CircleCI seems to be using 2.2.0.

Here's what I see in CircleCI's logs:

> /home/ubuntu/my-project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/htmlentities-4.3.2/lib/htmlentities/mappings/expanded.rb:465: warning: duplicated key at line 466 ignored: "inodot"

Notice the `2.2.0` in that path.

How can I get CircleCI to use the right Ruby version?

Answer (score -1):

CircleCI uses RVM to provide access to different Ruby versions. You can specify the ruby version to be used in circle.yml file as follows.

```
machine:
  ruby:
    version: rbx-2.2.2
```

Reference doc: https://circleci.com/docs/language-ruby-on-rails